# gets() function string behaviour

Tags: c, if-statement, gets

I have a small problem using gets function and a simple if expression.
It has to check whether the input is correct or no, in this case should be:  !S

```
char checkCommand[5];
gets(checkCommand);
if(checkCommand=="!S")....;
else puts("Invalid command!");
```

How come I never end up to get true value for the expression,
even if I type !S ? Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Also note that the gets() function has been removed from the C language since it was deemed broken beyond repair. You should use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you do not compare strings in C like this: `(checkCommand=="!S")`

To compare strings, you should use `strcmp` or `strncmp` or `memcmp` functions.

Example: In your case you use it like this:

`if (strncmp(checkCommand, "!S", 5) == 0)`

To read more about these functions, visit [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/?kw=strncmp) and similar.

You should also have noticed a warning "`gets` is dangerous..." something like this. You should avoid using `gets` and use `fgets` instead. The reason is well explained by *Chris Jester-Young* in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

C has no strings; it has character pointers, and `==` simply compares the pointers. Use `strcmp` or `strcasecmp` (if your system has that) to compare strings. Note that `strcmp` returns 0 when the strings compare equally.

Also, avoid using `gets`. If a user enters a string longer than 4 characters (in your case), other parts of your memory will start getting scribbled on. Instead, prefer to use `fgets`, which allows you to specify the size of your input buffer.

Comment: "C has no strings" shouldn't be stated like that. C has no specific data type for strings, but a string in C is a `0` terminated `char` array.

Comment: [pedantic] _"it has character pointers"_ -> it has char arrays and pointers to chars. A `char *` needn't be a string ( `scanf(" %c", &some_char);`)

Answer (score 0):

You must use strcmp() function to compare two strings in c

```
 int ret;
 ret=strcmp(checkCommand,"!s");
 if(ret!=0)   
 {
 printf("Invalid Command");
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace `if(checkCommand=="!S")` -> `if(!strcmp(checkcommand,"!S"))`

Comment: Also, the return value isn't used correctly; 0 means equal comparison (assuming `strcmp` instead of `strcpy` of course).

Comment: Yes strcmp instead of strcpy. i typed wrong.